# Postgres full text search with better match

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have this scripts for full text searching in my postgres database:

function for unaccent concat:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_concat_ws_unaccent(text, VARIADIC text[])
RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS 'SELECT unaccent(array_to_string($2, $1)
```

and this script is for full text search:

```
SELECT * FROM geocode.addresses
WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', f_concat_ws_unaccent(' ', country, city,street, housenumber, postcode))
    @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', 'some address') limit 1;
```

Can you help mi edit this select or create some function, which return result with the best match. For example in my database exist 2 cities. First city called  **CityA** and second city is composite from 2 words, where one word is same as name first city .. for example **Upper CityA**. When I execute my script like this:

```
SELECT * FROM geocode.addresses
WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', f_concat_ws_unaccent(' ', country, city,street, housenumber, postcode))
    @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', 'CityA') limit 1;
```

I need result with the best match row, but scipt return my **Upper CityA** row instead **CityA**.
Any ideas how can I edit this for required result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort by [ts_rank()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-controls.html) or ts_rank_cd()

By default, those terms would give the same ranks, but you can normalize by length

Try:

```
select
  *
from geocode.addresses
where
  ...
order by 
  ts_rank( to_tsvector(...), plainto_tsquery(...), 1) desc
limit 1
```

Where the `ts_rank(..., ..., 1)` divides the rank by 1 + the logarithm of the document length

There are other ts_rank normalizations in the link